# At what point does a dead person's image enter the public domain?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property

Apparently the Ronald Reagan Institute claims to own Ronald Reagan's image and [claims the ability to prevent the use of his image for commercial gain](https://www.chron.com/news/article/RNC-Trump-campaign-told-to-stop-using-President-15434408.php).

I am pretty sure I am allowed to sell pictures of George Washington, Abraham Lincoln, and John F. Kennedy for profit. But I can't sell images of Ronald Reagan for profit?

At what point does a person's image enter the public domain?

Answer (score 2):

### In California, [70 years](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_rights)

This is statutorily determined by the [Celebrities Rights Act](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Celebrities_Rights_Act) passed in 1985. Before that, such rights were not inheritable following [Lugosi v Universal Pictures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lugosi_v._Universal_Pictures).

California law applies because Reagan was a California resident at the time of his death.